# How can I view most recent Slack activity or save a search?

Tags: slack

This question has been asked before:

"I have a few unread messages among my dozens of Slack channels.
I click one my channels to read the new message there. I quickly remember I need to respond to something on a different channel so I jump there and send the response.
But now I've forgotten which channel I was on just before this, and the channel name isn't bolded anymore.
How can I see a list of recent channel activity, chronologically?"

The best answer is to search for:

before:2021-09-17 after:2021-06-16

which is tomorrow's date and three months ago. Also one should add the "Only include channels I'm in" under more filters.

But this is a bit of a fiddly thing to have to do each time.

Can I save this search somewhere? Frankly I'd just always want to view slack this way. I seem to lose notifications all the time.